# Why INavigationFilter.Filter(...) called twice?

Tags: orchardcms

There is an implementation of INavigationFilter that populate menu items for a content type. The problem is a method Filter() from it is called twice from two threads and twice as many menu items are created in the end.

Here is a log :

> 2012-10-15 18:35:50,650 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Filtering Home
>   2012-10-15 18:35:50,651 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Filtering 
>   2012-10-15 18:35:50,665 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Filtering Home
>   2012-10-15 18:35:50,666 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Filtering 
>   2012-10-15 18:35:50,693 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Rock plants, position 5. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,698 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Aquatic plants, position 7. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,700 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Wetland plants, position 6. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,702 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Rock plants, position 5. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,704 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Aquatic plants, position 7. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,706 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Wetland plants, position 6. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,708 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Herbacious plants, position 4. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,710 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Woody plants, position 3. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,711 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Lichens & Mosses, position 1. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,712 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Herbacious plants, position 4. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,714 [14]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Ferns & Allies, position 2. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,722 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Woody plants, position 3. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,724 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Lichens & Mosses, position 1. 2012-10-15 18:35:50,726 [37]
>   Zulatm.WebPlants.Handlers.TaxonomyNavigationFilter - Yielding item
>   Ferns & Allies, position 2.

of the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<MenuItem> Filter(IEnumerable<MenuItem> menuItems) {

             foreach (var item in menuItems) {
                 Logger.Debug(string.Format("Filtering {0}", item.Text));
                 if (item.Content != null && item.Content.ContentItem.ContentType == "TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem") {
                     var taxonomyCatalogId = _contentManager
                         .Query("Taxonomy")
                         .Where<TitlePartRecord>(t => t.Title == Migrations.STR_catalogTaxonomyName)
                         .List().Single().Id;

                     IEnumerable<TermPart> termParts = _contentManager
                         .Query<TermPart, TermPartRecord>()
                         .Where(record => record.TaxonomyId == taxonomyCatalogId)
                         .List();

                     var termsOnZeroLevel = termParts.Where(part => part.GetLevels() == 0);

                     foreach (var termPart in termsOnZeroLevel) {
                         var termMenuItem = new MenuItem();

                         InitializeTermMenuItem(termMenuItem, termPart, termParts);

                         Logger.Debug(string.Format("Yielding item {0}, position {1}.", termMenuItem.Text, termMenuItem.Position) );
                         yield return termMenuItem;
                     }
                 }
                 yield return item;
             }
        }
```

UPDATE.

```
private void InitializeTermMenuItem(MenuItem termMenuItem, TermPart currentTerm, IEnumerable<TermPart> allTerms, string parentPosition = "") {

var currentPosition =
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentPosition)
                    ? currentTerm.Weight.ToString()
                    : string.Join(".", parentPosition, currentTerm.Weight);

        termMenuItem.RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(
            new {
                action = "Item",
                controller = "Home",
                area = "Contrib.Taxonomies",
                termPath = currentTerm.Slug
            });
        termMenuItem.Text = T(currentTerm.As<TitlePart>().Title);
        termMenuItem.Classes.Add("MyTaxonomyClass" + currentTerm.As<TitlePart>().Title);
        termMenuItem.Position = currentPosition;
        termMenuItem.Items = new List<MenuItem>();

        var childMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        termMenuItem.Items = childMenuItems;
        foreach (var childTerm in allTerms.Where(p => p.Path.StartsWith(currentTerm.FullPath))) {
            var newChildMenuItem = new MenuItem();
            InitializeTermMenuItem(newChildMenuItem, childTerm, allTerms, currentPosition);
                childMenuItems.Add(newChildMenuItem);
            }
 }
```

UPDATE 2.

```
public int UpdateFrom11() {
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(
        "TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem",
        cfg => cfg
                   .WithPart("MenuPart")
                   .WithPart("CommonPart")
                   .DisplayedAs("Taxonomy catalog menu item")
                   .WithSetting("Description", "Injects taxonomy categories as menu items")
                   .WithSetting("Stereotype", "MenuItem")
        );
    return 12;
}

public int UpdateFrom12() {
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(
        "TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem",
        cfg => cfg.WithPart("IdentityPart"));
    return 13;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `yield return item;` at the end with `else { yield return item; }`. I guess you don't want to output the base item, but exchange it with a collection of dynamically built items, right?

Comment: Also, please provide the method `InitializeTermMenuItem`. And make sure you don't have your *"TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem"* appearing twice in the actual menu. From what I see it would then make all items appear twice, as the items returned from this filter are always the same for every *"TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem"*.

Comment: Keep in mind that filter does not build hierarchy - it just outputs a flat list of items, from which the hierarchy is built in the next step. So if you need the generated items to appear exactly in place of or beneath parent (the *"TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem"*) you also need to set the position accordingly (if the parent is *1*, then children need to be *1.1*, *1.2* and so on). You're not doing that.

Comment: Thank you Piotr for your responses! Tried the enclosing in "else" the last statement without success. The "TaxonomyNavigationMenuItem" is added only once. Also please see updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed that. Initialized MenuItem.Content and the second copy gone. That helped because the following code generated a copy of current menu item. It took me a time to find it out.

In MenuWidgetPartDriver.Display(..):

```
var localized = new List<MenuItem>();
foreach(var menuItem in menuItems) {
    // if there is no associated content, it as culture neutral
    if(menuItem.Content == null) {
        localized.Add(menuItem);
    }

    // if the menu item is culture neutral or of the current culture
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem.Culture) || String.Equals(menuItem.Culture, currentCulture, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        localized.Add(menuItem);
    }
}

menuItems = localized;
```